# Has the distributional Laplacian $\Delta f:C_c^\infty(\Omega)'\to C_c^\infty(\Omega)'$ a unique extension in $H_0^1(\Omega)'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $$H=\overline{\mathcal D}^{\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H}\tag 1$$ with $$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle_H:=\langle\phi,\psi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}+\langle\nabla\phi,\nabla\psi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for }\phi,\psi\in\mathcal D$$

> Let $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ be weakly differentiable (with $\nabla u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$). Then, $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ is called **weak Laplacian** of $u$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\langle\phi,v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}=-\langle\nabla u,\nabla\phi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D\tag 2\;.$$ In that case, we write $\Delta u:=v$.

Let $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Can we show that $\Delta f$ with $$(\Delta f)(u):=\langle\Delta u,f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}\;\;\;\text{for }u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$$ is an element of $H_0^1(\Omega)'$?

Comment: how is it not a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855228/definition-of-the-laplacian-as-an-operator-from-h-01-omega-to-h-01-omega/  ? you think replacing $\partial_{x_i}^2 f$ by $\Delta f$ changes what ?

Comment: Your notation is quite confusing. $\Delta u$ is not really a function in $L^2$, so $\langle \Delta u, f\rangle$ does not really mean the usual $L^2$ product. However, if you use $-\langle \nabla u, \nabla f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega, \mathbb R^d)}$, it is not clear why $\nabla f $ exists. Which texts are you following?

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm not sure about the definition of the weak Laplacian. Obviously, in order for $(2)$ to make sense, we need that $u\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ and that $u$ has a weak gradient $\nabla u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$. A solution $v$ needs to be in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. However, it's clear that (see my comment below the answer of user1952009) any $u\in H_0^2(\Omega)$ has a weak Laplacian in the sense of $(2)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar : he follows https://www.mat.tuhh.de/veranstaltungen/isem18/images/0/02/Lecture13.pdf

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Note that you have asked several question recently and it seems that you are quite messed up with the definitions. There **are** at least two different definitions of weak Laplacian, it will be easier for you and me to if we follow a fixed reference.

Comment: @ArcticChar You're right, I'm quite messed up with the definitions. It's not totally clear to me in which way they are consistent. I've asked a [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860139/relationship-between-the-distributional-laplacian-and-the-weak-laplacian) in the hope to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's take $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\varphi,f \in C^\infty_c((0,1))$.

Then $$\langle f'',\varphi  \rangle = \int_0^1 f''(x) \varphi (x) dx = f'(1)\varphi (1)-f'(0)\varphi (0) - \int_0^{1} f'(x) \varphi '(x) dx$$

$\varphi,f$ have their support strictly inside $(0,1)$ so $f'(0)\varphi (0) = f'(1)\varphi (1)= 0$ and

$$\langle f'',\varphi  \rangle =-\langle f',\varphi'  \rangle$$

Then with  $\|u\|_{H^1_0} = \|u\|_{L^2}+\|u'\|_{L^2} \ge \|u'\|_{L^2}$ and the Cauchy inequality you have $$|\langle f',\varphi'  \rangle| \le   \|f'\|_{L^2}\|\varphi'\|_{L^2}\le \|f'\|_{L^2}\|\varphi\|_{H^1_0} \le \|f\|_{H^1_0}\|\varphi\|_{H^1_0}$$

The conclusion is that **since $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, all this stays true for any $\varphi,f \in H^1_0([0,1])$** (this is where $H^1_0$ makes a huge difference to $H^1$)

Replacing $'$ by $\nabla$ it extends to any domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and

- $u \mapsto \langle \Delta f,u  \rangle$ is a bounded operator $H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{C}$ whenever $f \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
- $f \mapsto \langle \Delta f,.  \rangle$ is bounded when seen as an operator $H^1_0(\Omega) \to H^1_0(\Omega)'$

Comment: If $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that $v_i$ is weakly partially differentiable wrt the $i$-th variable, then $v$ has a weak divergence $\nabla\cdot u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. Since the weak Laplacian of $u$ is the weak divergence of $\nabla u$, we should need that $\partial_iu$ is weakly partially differentiable wrt the $i$-th variable, i.e. we should need something like $u\in H_0^2(\Omega)$. Or is there something wrong in my argumentation?

Comment: I just proved that $\langle f'',\varphi \rangle =-\langle f',\varphi' \rangle$ whenever $f,\varphi \in H^1_0$ ( $f''$ is the distributional derivative of $f'$). And please take $\Omega = [0,1]$ @0xbadf00d

Comment: What do you denote by $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$? The duality bracket?

Comment: I wrote it.. 1st line (I make things simple, you make them complicated) @0xbadf00d

Comment: So, the $L^2$-inner product?! But then, how do you make sense of $\langle f'',\varphi \rangle =-\langle f',\varphi' \rangle$, if you consider $f''$ as a distribution?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : come on... WE DO NOT NEED OF DISTRIBUTIONS HERE see my answer, I use only $C^\infty_c$ functions. And the second derivative is a densely defined unbounded operator $L^2 \to L^2$ so really you don't need distributions

Comment: @0xbadf00d : do you know how to prove that $C^\infty_c([0,1])$ is dense in $H^1_0([0,1])$ but not in $H^1([0,1])$ ? (for a $u \in H^1_0$, consider a $C^\infty_c$ approximation of its derivative)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that your $f$ is in $C_c^\infty$. However, I don't understand how we can conclude that everything stays true for $f\in H_0^1$. Yes, $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $H_0^1$ and you've proved that $C_c^\infty\ni\varphi\mapsto\langle f'',\varphi\rangle$ is bounded. By density, $H_0^1\ni u\mapsto\langle f'',u\rangle$ is bounded too, but I don't understand why we can choose $f\in H_0^1$. Wouldn't that imply that $f''\in L^2$? But we don't know that from $f\in H_0^1$.

Comment: as usual because it is true on a dense subset of $H^1_0$ @0xbadf00d  and you don't need that $f'' \in L^2$ for defining $\langle f'',\varphi \rangle$ since it is $= -\langle f',\varphi' \rangle$

Comment: I don't get why we only need to consider $\Omega=[0,1]$. Why can we conclude that it holds for any open $\Omega$ (you've said "domain", i.e. a connected, nonempty, open set, but I'm not sure if you really meant that).

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I just integrated by parts... don't you think it works in $\mathbb{R}^d$ too ?

Comment: I don't see anything which is easier for $\Omega=[0,1]$. So, why is it worth to be considered?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : very funny. And $C^\infty_c$ is made exactly for simplifying the integration by parts

Comment: I don't understand you. Look, $$ι:L^2(Ω)\to H'\;,\;\;\;u\mapsto\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,u\rangle\right|_H$$ is injective and hence $L^2(Ω)$ can be identified with $ι(L^2(Ω))$ (which is dense in  $H'$). If $Δ$ is the mapping $\mathcal D\to\mathcal D$ and $ϕ∈\mathcal D$, then $$|ι(Δϕ)ψ|=|\langle∇ψ,∇ϕ\rangle|\le\left\|∇ψ\right\|\left\|∇ϕ\right\|$$ for all $ψ∈\mathcal D$ and hence $\left.ι(Δϕ)\right|_{\mathcal D}$ is a densely-defined bounded linear functional on $H$ and its operator norm is at most $\left\|∇ϕ\right\|$. So, it can be uniquely extended in $H'$. No need to choose a special $Ω$.

Comment: If $Δϕ$ denotes this extension, then $$\left\|\Deltaϕ\right\|_{H'}\le\left\|∇ϕ\right\|\le\left\|\phi\right\|_H$$ and hence $\Delta$ can be uniquely extended to a bounded operator $H\to H'$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : how is it different to my answer above ? And after what you wrote I just used that $H^1_0$ is the completion of $ C^\infty_c, \|.\|_{H^1}$ i.e. of your $H$  (and I posted this answer because the trick $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $H^1_0$ is elegant, and also important for understanding why it doesn't work when you replace $H^1_0$ by some other space)