# Relationship between the distributional Laplacian and the weak Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ denote the $L^2(\Omega)$- or $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$-inner product (depending on the context)
- $\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $$H:=\overline{\mathcal D}^{\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H}$$ with $$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle_H:=\langle\phi,\psi\rangle+\langle\nabla\phi,\nabla\psi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }\phi,\psi\in\mathcal D$$

---

Let $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\phi):=-p\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D$$ and $\nabla p:=\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_d}\right)^T$ for $p\in\mathcal D'$ and $$(\nabla\cdot p)(\phi):=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_i}(\phi)\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D$$ for $p\in(\mathcal D')^d$. Then, $$\Delta p:=\nabla\cdot\nabla p$$ is the **distributional Laplacian** of $p\in\mathcal D$ and it's easy to see that $$(\Delta p)(\phi)=p(\Delta\phi)\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D\;.\tag 1$$

---

Now, each $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ can be identified with some unique $\langle f\rangle\in\mathcal D'$ via $$\langle f\rangle:=\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,f\rangle\right|_{\mathcal D}\;.$$ Let $\phi\in\mathcal D$. We can show that $\Delta\langle\phi\rangle$ has a unique extension $F\in H'$ with $$F(v)=-\langle\nabla v,\nabla\phi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }v\in H\;.\tag 2$$ We continue to denote $F$ by $\Delta\langle\phi\rangle$. In the same way $\Delta\langle\;\cdot\;\rangle:\mathcal D\to H'$ has a unique extension $L\in\mathfrak L(H,H')$ with $$(Lu)v=-\langle\nabla v,\nabla u\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }u,v\in H\;.\tag 3$$

---

If $u\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ is weakly differentiable, then $v\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ is called **weak Laplacian** of $u$, if $$\langle\phi,v\rangle=-\langle\nabla u,\nabla\phi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D\tag 4\;.$$ In that case, we write $\Delta u:=v$ and $$(\Delta\langle u\rangle)\psi=\langle\Delta u\rangle(\psi)=\langle\psi,\Delta u\rangle=-\langle\nabla\psi,\nabla u\rangle=(Lu)\psi\;\;\;\text{for all }\psi\in\mathcal D\;.\tag 5$$

> If each $u\in H$ would admit a weak Laplacian $\Delta u$, it would make sense to continue to denote $L$ by $\Delta\langle\;\cdot\;\rangle$ and the relationship to the weak Laplacian would be clear. So, does each $u$ admit a weak Laplacian in the sense of $(4)$?

Comment: For $u \in H$, we know that $Lu \in H'$. Moreover, we have that $ \langle Lu, \varphi\rangle_{H', H} := \langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi  \rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for all $\varphi \in H$. For $u$ to admit a weak Laplacian, we need a function $\phi \in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ such that $\langle Lu, \varphi\rangle_{H', H} = \langle \phi, \varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)} =: \langle \phi, \varphi\rangle_{H', H}$ for all $\varphi \in H$. Thus, $u$ admits a weak Laplacian iff $Lu \in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$. Does this help you to answer your question?

Comment: they are the same on $C^\infty_c$ and $H^1_0$ a dense subset, that's all we need to know. When the distributional Laplacian is really a distribution (say with Dirac deltas) then the weak-Laplacian too (or it isn't defined). I think you really need to take some examples, for example $u(x) = 1-|x|$ on  $H^1_0([-1,1])$.

Comment: And did you define the tempered distributions (the dual of Schwartz functions) ? They are really simple, and let you define almost every distributions, in particular all the derivatives of any compactly supported continuous function. And you didn't explain your problem about the Stokes operator yet. Why do you care about ? What do you want to show ?

Comment: @Mike I can't follow your reasoning. Let $u\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ be weakly differentiable and $v\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$. Then, $v$ is the weak Laplacian of u in the sense of $(4)$ if and only if $$\langle\phi,v\rangle=(Lu)\phi\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D\;.$$ How do you deduce $Lu\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ from that? And what exactly do you understand by the claim $\Phi\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ for $\Phi\in H'$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d:You already mentioned that a function $v \in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ can be identified with a distribution $\langle v \rangle \in \mathcal{D}'$. In fact, $\langle v \rangle \in H'$. So every weak Laplacian $v \in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ induces a distribution $\langle v \rangle \in H'$. Let $v$ be the weak Laplacian of $u$. I claim that $\langle v \rangle$ is the distributional Laplacian of $u$. To see this, note that $(4)$ holds for all $\phi \in H$ (density of $\mathcal{D}$). Now your question boils down to:

Comment: Given the distributional Laplace operator $Lu \in H'$, does there exist a $\phi \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that $\langle \phi \rangle = Lu$ in $H'$? This is only the case if $Lu \in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$. So, to answer your question: No, there are functions $u \in H$ that admit no weak Laplacian. (This is similar to the statement that there are functions $v \in L^2(\Omega)$ which are not in $H^1(\Omega)$)

Comment: @Mike Why is $\langle v\rangle\in H'$ for all $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$? I don't think that this is true, cause all we're able to show should be $$\left|\langle v\rangle(\phi)\right|\le\left\|\phi v\right\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\le\left\|\phi\right\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\left\|1_{ \operatorname{supp}\phi}f\right\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D$$

Comment: @Mike Please respond to my last comment.

Comment: @0xbadf00d How did you define $(\Delta p)(\phi)$? Was $\Delta p$ the distribution determined by $\Delta p$? Precisely, was it defined by $$(\Delta p)(\phi)=\int\phi\Delta p?$$ Thank you.