# Let $\Delta u$ have a representation in $L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$. Does $u$ have a representation in $H^1 (\mathbb R^d)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, laplacian

Let $D (\mathbb R^d)$ is the space of test functions and $D' (\mathbb R^d)$ that of distributions. For $u \in D' (\mathbb R^d)$, its [distributional Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1855244/368425) $\Delta u \in D' (\mathbb R^d)$ is defined by
$$
_{D'} \langle \Delta u, \varphi \rangle_D := {_{D'}} \langle  u, \Delta \varphi \rangle_D ,
\quad \varphi \in D (\mathbb R^d).
$$

Assume that $\Delta u$ has a representation in $L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$, i.e., there is $f \in L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$ such that
$$
_{D'} \langle \Delta u, \varphi \rangle_D := \int_{\mathbb R^d} f  (\Delta \varphi),
\quad \varphi \in D (\mathbb R^d).
$$

> Does $u$ have a representation in $H^1 (\mathbb R^d)$?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily. One easy way to construct a counterexample is to take $v \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and then consider the distribution $u = 1+ v$. Then the distributional Laplacian of $u$ coincides with distributional Laplacian of $v$ since $\Delta 1 = 0$. As a result, $\Delta u$ has such a representation but we clearly do not have $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: Isn't $u = 1$ already a counterexample?

Comment: @gerw Of course that's an especially simple special case of this kind of counterexample. I like this slightly more general counterexample because I find it illustrates a bit better what part of the behavior you are failing to control